# The datagrid not showing the child element of xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am doing task of loading online xml file into datagrid, I done it but in xml file there is child nodes such as,

```
        <quantity>-54</quantity>
        <weight>1.000</weight>
        <categories>
            <category>Cradles &amp; Holders</category>
            <category>iPhone &amp; iPod Accessories</category>
            <category>FM Transmitters</category>
        </categories>
```

The datagrid showing the `<quantity>`,`<weight>` as a column and its data, but truncate  node and also not showing the data also.

My question is that how I add them or manage the child node to show in datagrid.